# The difference between 初めて, 最初に and 最初

Tags: words

> 初めて日本に行った時、友達のお母さんが伝統的な和式朝食を作ってくれました。
>
> The first time I went to Japan, my friend's mother made me a traditional Japanese breakfast.

If I wrote the opening of the sentence in the following manner, how would the meaning change?

> 最初に日本に行った時、

or

> 最初日本に行った時、

In this context, what is the difference between 初めて, 最初に and 最初?

Comment: What do you think 最 means?

Comment: most, as in 最 (most) + 初 (first time) = 最初 beginning;  outset;  first;  onset.

Comment: @Chris: What is the purpose of your question?

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto I think 最初 implies that there exists something after the first event.

Comment: @Chris do you think 初めて implies that something does not exist after the first event?

Comment: @yadokari No. I think it could exist, but it doesn't have to.

Comment: @Chris, ok i was confused by your wording "there exists something after the first event." Actually, though... would you use 初めて　in this manner if it was only expressing a one time occurrence? Can you give me an example?

Comment: @yadokari How about the first time you try to do something? 「今日初めてやってみた。」I don't think that would imply that something will occur or has to occur later.

Comment: @Chris: I see.  I think that 最初 indeed implies that there is something after that, but I do not think that that explains the difference between 初めて日本に行った時… and 最初に日本に行った時….  I feel that there are other differences which make 初めて sound more natural than 最初に in this case.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto I agree that there are other differences. Yet, the one I thought of seemed the most obvious to me.

Answer (score 7):

Here is my reasoning.

最初 refers to the beginning of a time period or to the beginning of a series of events. (Cf. 日本に来たばかりのとき...)

As istrasci pointed out in his answer, the additional に strengthens the time reference. (Cf. 日曜日街に行く vs. 日曜日に街に行く.)

初めて is used, as far as I can tell exclusively, for things you do for the first time. (Cf. 初めて見た.)

The difference between

```
初めて日本に行ったとき、
最初日本に行ったとき、
```

is maybe best reflected in English as

```
When I went to Japan for the first time, [the first thing I did was to find a convenience store and eat natto and I loved it.]
When I first went to Japan, [I could hardly understand a word of what people said.]
```

In the first sentence, you talk about what Japan was like for you, as a first impression. In the second sentence, you simply talk about the time period, which coincides with your arrival in Japan.

Comment: +1 This was the only reason I could come up with as well.

Answer (score 1):

`最初に` sounds wrong in your example.  `最初日本に行った時` I believe is correct.  The additional `に` is only needed if the "first" is like in a list of steps, or describing who/what is the first to do something.

> - 最初彼に会ったときにはあまり強い印象を受けなかった。　→　The first time I met him, he did not make much of an impression on me.
> - まず最初 **に** ゆでて，次に味付けする。　→　First boil it and then season it.
> - 最初 **に** 到着したのはトムだった。　→　Tom was the first to arrive ("The first to arrive was Tom").

Other than that point, assuming your second sentence is then just `最初日本に行った時`, then they basically mean the same thing.  The only thing I would say is that `最初` kind of implies many times, whereas `初めて` doesn't necessarily imply any number of repetitions.  At least that's the feeling I get from them, but that could just be me.

Comment: I originally wrote 最初日本に行った時, then was corrected by a native speaker to 初めて日本に行った時. In her explanation she had changed it to 最初に日本に行った時.here is what she said:
「最初に日本に行った」は、旅のスタート地点が日本だったと言っているようにも受け取れますし、何回か日本を訪れたうちの１回目を指しているようにも受け取れます。「初めて日本に行った」のほうがvery first time to go to Japanと、その時の事を指していることがはっきりと分かります。

Comment: I do not think I recognize any difference between 最初 and 最初に in this case….  初めて is more natural than both of them in this case.

Comment: @yadokari: I agree with the native speaker that 初めて日本に行った時 sounds more natural than 最初に日本に行った時.  I also agree that 最初(に)日本に行った時 can mean a different thing as she explained, but I am not sure if that is the reason it sounds less natural to me.